# How to change bitnami_wordpress stack directory path /wordpress

Tags: wordpress, bitnami

I know this might be simple for other, but I've tried and look everywhere with no solution: I'm trying to change url to be http://example.com/whatever as opposed to www.example.com/wordpress in the bitnami wordpress stack.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to go from http://localhost/wordpress to http://localhost/whatever I'm using bitnami stack on a windows 8 machine if that helps. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit `installdir/apps/wordpress/conf/httpd-prefix.conf` with the new prefix that you want to use. Then restart Apache. If it is not enough, check wp-config.php to see if there are references to /wordpress in the file.